# My match/merge process is not creating relationships in the Neo4J database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, graph-data-science

I am very new to Neo4j/cypher/graph databases, and have been trying to follow the [Neo4j tutorial](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/#export-csv) to import data I have in a `csv` and create relationships.

The following code does what I want in terms of reading in the data, creating nodes, and setting properties.

```
/* Importing data on seller-buyer relationshsips */
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///customer_rel_table.tsv' AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (seller:Seller {sellerID: row.seller})
    ON CREATE SET seller += {name: row.seller_name,
                             root_eid: row.vendor_eid,
                             city: row.city}
MERGE (buyer:Buyer {buyerID: row.buyer})
    ON CREATE SET buyer += {name: row.buyer_name};


/* Creating indices for the properties I might want to match on */
CREATE INDEX seller_id FOR (s:Seller) on (s.seller_name);
CREATE INDEX buyer_id FOR (b:Buyer) on (b.buyer_name);

/* Creating constraints to guarantee buyer-seller pairs are not duplicated */
CREATE CONSTRAINT sellerID ON (s:Seller) ASSERT s.sellerID IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT buyerID on (b:Buyer) ASSERT b.buyerID IS UNIQUE;
```

Now I have the nodes (sellers and buyers) that I want, and I would like to link buyers and sellers. The code I have tried for this is:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///customer_rel_table.tsv' AS row
MATCH (s:Seller {sellerID: row.seller})
MATCH (b:Buyer {buyerID: row.buyer})
MERGE (s)-[st:SOLD_TO]->(b)
```

The query runs, but I don't get any relationships:

`Query executed in 294ms. Query type: WRITE_ONLY.
No results.`

Since I'm not asking it to `RETURN` anything, I think the "No results" comment is correct, but when I look at metadata for the DB, no relationships appear. Also, my data has ~220K rows, so 294ms seems fast.

EDIT: At @cybersam's prompting, I tried this query: 
`MATCH p=(:Seller)-[:SOLD_TO]->(:Buyer) RETURN p`, which gives `No results.`

For clarity, there are two fields in my data that are the heart of the relationship: 
`seller` and `buyer`, where the seller sells stuff to the buyer. The seller identifiers are repeated, but for each seller there are unique seller-buyer pairs.

What do I need to fix in my code to get relationships between the `sellers` and `buyers`? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, `s.seller_name` and `b.buyer_name` do not exist, so the indexes will be empty. You should use `s.name` and `b.name` instead. This issue should not be relevant to your question, though.

Comment: Does this query return anything?: `MATCH p=(:Seller)-[:SOLD_TO]->(:Buyer) RETURN p`

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for the pointer! And no, unfortunately, it doesn't. That's good to note; I'll edit my question.

Comment: But the DB does have `Buyer` and `Seller` nodes?

Comment: @cybersam It does. MATCH (n:Seller) RETURN (n) LIMIT 25 gives me back 25 nodes. Same for Buyer

Comment: Oh, your second query does not specify `FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'`!

Comment: :headdesk: That did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query's `LOAD CSV` clause does not specify `FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'`. The default terminator is a comma (','). That is probably why it fails to `MATCH` anything.

Try adding `FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'` at the end of that clause.